# New to VBA: Block if without end if

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to send the user an error message based on two different values on an excel sheet. I keep getting a "Block if without end if" error.

```
Sub Cellname()
'
' Cellname Macro

    If Range("E1").Value <> Range("G1").Value Then
        MsgBox "All Tier 2 Escalated Incidents are tracked."

    If Range("E1").Value > Range("G1").Value Then
        MsgBox "More Tier 2 Escalated ideas are currently being tracked than are present on the datasheet. Check Tracked Status."

    If Range("E1").Value < Range("G1").Value Then
        MsgBox "New Tier 2 Escalated ideas may be available. Check the datasheet"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You've opened 3 `If` blocks but only `End If` for one of them. Try adding two more `End If` lines...

Comment: Either that your use `ElseIf`

Comment: Looks like you need to replace the 2nd and 3rd If with ElseIf or make a Select...Case statement.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's `ElseIf` he wants because the 2nd and 3rd conditions are not mutually exclusive of the first... it means the 2nd and 3rd conditions will never be called?

Comment: Also check whether your first condition really is meant to be `<>` - I suspect that message is meant to be displayed when the two values are equal, not when they are different.

Comment: There is no question in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing an IF statement with no else and only one command, you don't need END IF at all. Although, I believe you may want ElseIF's to make this work logically.
Just keep the code all one one line for each If statement like this:

```
 If Range("E1").Value <> Range("G1").Value Then MsgBox "All Tier 2 Escalated Incidents are tracked."

    If Range("E1").Value > Range("G1").Value Then MsgBox "More Tier 2 Escalated ideas are currently being tracked than are present on the datasheet. Check Tracked Status."

    If Range("E1").Value < Range("G1").Value Then MsgBox "New Tier 2 Escalated ideas may be available. Check the datasheet"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ElseIf to add more than one condition to a single IF-THEN statement.

```
If Range("E1").Value <> Range("G1").Value Then
    MsgBox "All Tier 2 Escalated Incidents are tracked."

ElseIf Range("E1").Value > Range("G1").Value Then
    MsgBox "More Tier 2 Escalated ideas are currently being tracked than are present on the datasheet. Check Tracked Status."

ElseIf Range("E1").Value < Range("G1").Value Then
    MsgBox "New Tier 2 Escalated ideas may be available. Check the datasheet"

End If
```

Otherwise add an End If after each If statement.

Comment: It has to be End If * 3 - 
 
I don't think it's ElseIf he wants because the 2nd and 3rd conditions are not mutually exclusive of the first... it means the 2nd and 3rd conditions will never be called?

Comment: I agree with @jamheadart ... with one caveat: based on the messages being displayed I suspect that the first `If` was meant to be a `=` (in which case the `ElseIf`s will be accessible).

Comment: as stated the code DOES NOT cover the equal scenario, it covers not equal, less than, greater than.