# Excel FindJobCode's problems

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA and I have a code as below to find some job numbers in a description.
However, i have 3 problems on it...

1. if 1st character is small letter such as "s", "m", then it show error
2. i cannot solve Example3, the result will show "M3045.67," but all i need is "M3045.67" only, no comma
3. i don't know why it is failed to run the code  Range("E2").Value = "Overhead" after Else  in Example5

but for problem 3, i can run result "overhead" before i add 2nd criteria, is something wrong there ? Please help~~~thanks.

P.S. the looping will be added after solving above questions......

```vb
Sub FindCode()
        
        'Example1 : G5012.123 Management Fee / Get Result = G5012.123
        'Example2 : G3045.67 Management Fee / Get Result = G3045.67
        'Example3 : M3045.67, S7066 Retenal Fee / Get Result = M3045.67,
        'Example4 : P9876-123A Car Park / Get Result = P9876
        'Example5 : A4 paper / Get result = Overehad
        
        'Criteria1 : 1st Character = G / S / M / P
        If Left(Range("A2"), 1) = "G" Or Left(Range("A2"), 1) = "S" Or Left(Range("A2"), 1) = "M" Or Left(Range("A2"), 1) = "P" Then
            'Criteria2 : 2nd-5th Character = Number only
            If IsNumeric(Mid(Range("A2"), 2, 4)) Then
                'Get string before "space"
                Range("E2").Value = Left(Range("A2"), InStr(1, Range("A2"), " ") - 1)
        Else
                'If not beginning from Crit 1&2, show "Overhead"
                Range("E2").Value = "Overhead"
            End If
        End If
        
        'If start from "P", get first 5 string
        If Left(Range("A2"), 1) = "P" And IsNumeric(Mid(Range("A2"), 2, 4)) Then
            Range("E2").Value = Left(Range("A2"), 5)
        Else
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: For 1. You can use Ucase("string") to make any string upper case, and use this to make it case insensitive. So your first IF could be like;  `If InStr("GSMP", UCase(Left(Range("A2"), 1))) > 0 Then`

Comment: For 3, your indentation is wrong, and the `else` for "overhead" is for the second if, so it will only fire if it starts with the right letter, but then doesn't have numbers. The indentation not really affecting the code, but it's probably what threw you off. The `End If` needs to move up a bit.

Comment: Also, on 1, if you are using `InStr` like in my example, you don't really need `UCase` since it has that function built in. `If InStr(1, "GSMP", Left(Range("A2"), 1), 1) > 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks, i never know that GSMP can be combined like this short code and no need to split to 4 parts......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below will extract the job number and return it to the procedure that called it.

```
Function JobCode(Cell As Range) As String
    ' 303
        
        'Example1 : G5012.123 Management Fee / Get Result = G5012.123
        'Example2 : G3045.67 Management Fee / Get Result = G3045.67
        'Example3 : M3045.67, S7066 Rental Fee / Get Result = M3045.67,
        'Example4 : P9876-123A Car Park / Get Result = P9876
        'Example5 : A4 paper / Get result = Overhead
        
        Dim Fun     As String           ' function return value
        Dim Txt     As String           ' Text to extract number from
        
        ' Minimize the number of times your code reads from the sheet because it's slow
        Txt = Cell.Value                ' actually, it's Cells(2, 1)
        
        ' Criteria1 : 1st Character = G / S / M / P
        If InStr("GSMP", UCase(Left(Txt, 1))) Then
            Txt = Split(Txt)(0)                     ' split on blank, take first element
            ' Criteria2 : 2nd-5th Character = Number only
            ' Isnumeric(Mid("A4", 2, 4)) = true
            If (Len(Txt) >= 5) And (IsNumeric(Mid(Txt, 2, 4))) Then
                Fun = Replace(Txt, ",", "")
                Fun = Split(Fun, "-")(0)            ' discard "-123A" in example 4
            End If
        End If
        
        ' If no job number was extracted, show "Overhead"
        If Len(Fun) = 0 Then Fun = "Overhead"
        JobCode = Fun
End Function
```

The setup as a function, rather than a sub, is typical for this sort of search. In my trials I had your 5 examples in A2:A6 and called them in a loop, giving a different cell to the function on each loop. Very likely, this is what you are angling for, too. This is the calling procedure I used for testing.

```
Sub Test_JobCode()
    ' 303
    
    Dim R   As Long
    
    For R = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' I urge you not to use syntax for addressing ranges when addressing cells
        Debug.Print JobCode(Cells(R, "A"))          ' actually, it's Cells(2, 1)
    Next R
End Sub
```

Of course, instead of `Debug.Print JobCode(Cells(R, "A"))` you could also have `Cells(R, "B").Value = JobCode(Cells(R, "A"))`

The reason why your `Else` statement didn't work was a logical error. The "Overhead" caption doesn't apply if criteria 1 & 2 aren't met but if all previous efforts failed, which is slightly broader in meaning. This combined with the fact that `Isnumeric(Mid("A4", 2, 4)) = True`, causing the test not to fail as you expected.

In rough terms, the code first checks if the first letter qualifies the entry for examination (and returns "Overhead" if it doesn't). Then the text is split into words, only the first one being considered. If it's too short or non-numeric no job code is extracted resulting in "Overhead" in the next step. If this test is passed, the final result is modified: The trailing comma is removed (it it exists) and anything appended with a hyphen is removed (if it exists). I'm not sure you actually want this. So, you can easily remove the line. Or you might add more modifications at that point.

Comment: thanks, variatus, it seems cool and very short code, i use many function in excel (not vba) to do it before. i am new for vba so that the code seems so difficult to understand, but the output is what i want. thank you again

Comment: Great! Please test the code thoroughly and, if it passes muster, mark my answer as "Selected" as a guide to others. Thank you.

Comment: Why this code do not have "end if" but it can still work ? If Len(Fun) = 0 Then Fun = "Overhead"

Comment: it seems not a regular method to use if statement without end if : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/block-if-without-end-if

Comment: Srry, i find the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214859/new-to-vba-block-if-without-end-if

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is **FAR** easier using regular expression matching and replacing, so I recommend enabling that library of functions.  The best news about doing that is that you can invoke those functions in EXCEL formulas and do not need to use Visual Basic for Applications at all.

To enable Regular Expressions as Excel functions:
Step 1:  Enable the Regular Expression library in VBA.

```
A. In the Visual Basic for Applications window (where you enter VBA code) find the Tools menu and
   select it, then select the References... entry in the sub-menu.
B. A dialogue box will appear listing the possible "Available References:" in alphabetical order.
   Scroll down to find the entry "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5".
C. Check the checkbox on that line and press the OK button.
```

Step 2: Create function calls.  In the Visual Basic for Applications window select Insert..Module.  Then paste the following VBA code into the blank window that comes up:

```
'  Some function wrappers to make the VBScript RegExp reference Library useful in both VBA code and in Excel & Access formulas
'
Private rg As RegExp    'All of the input data to control the RegExp parsing
'  RegExp object contains 3 Boolean options that correspond to the 'i', 'g', and 'm' options in Unix-flavored regexp
'    IgnoreCase - pretty self-evident.  True means [A-Z] matches lowercase letters and vice versa, false means it won't
'    IsGlobal - True means after the first match has been processed, continue on from the current point in DataString and look to process more matches.  False means stop after first match is processed.
'    MultiLine - False means ^ and $ match only Start and End of DataString, True means they match embedded newlines.  This provides an option to process line-by-line when Global is true also.
'
'  Returns true/false: does DataString match pattern?  IsGlobal=True makes no sense here
Public Function RegExpMatch(DataString As String, Pattern As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional IsGlobal As Boolean = False, Optional MultiLine As Boolean = False) As Boolean
If rg Is Nothing Then Set rg = New RegExp
rg.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
rg.Global = IsGlobal
rg.MultiLine = MultiLine
rg.Pattern = Pattern
RegExpMatch = rg.Test(DataString)
End Function
'
'  Find <pattern> in <DataString>, replace with <ReplacePattern>
'       Default IsGlobal=True means replace all matching occurrences.  Call with False to replace only first occurrence.
'
Public Function RegExpReplace(DataString As String, Pattern As String, ReplacePattern As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional IsGlobal As Boolean = True, Optional MultiLine As Boolean = False) As String
If rg Is Nothing Then Set rg = New RegExp
rg.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
rg.Global = IsGlobal
rg.MultiLine = MultiLine
rg.Pattern = Pattern
RegExpReplace = rg.Replace(DataString, ReplacePattern)
End Function
```

Now you can call RegExpMatch & RegExpReplace in Excel formulas and we can start to think of how to solve your particular problem.  To be a match, your string must start with G, S, M, or P.  In a regular expression code that is ^[GSMP], where the up-arrow says to start at the beginning and the [GSMP] says to accept a G, S, M or P in the next position.  Then any matching string must next have a number of numeric digits.  Code that as \d+, where the \d means one numeric digit and the + is a modifier that means accept one or more of them.  Then you could have a dot followed by some more digits, or not.  This is a little more complicated - you would code it as (\.\d+)? because dot is a special character in regular expressions and \. says to accept a literal dot.  That is followed by \d+ which is one or more digits, but this whole expression is enclosed in parentheses and followed by a ?, which means what is in parentheses can appear once or not at all.  Finally, comes the rest of the line and we don't really care what is in it.  We code .*$ for zero or more characters (any) followed by the line's end.  That all goes together as `^[GSMP]\d+(\.\d+)?.*$`.

Putting that pattern into our RegExpReplace call:

```
=RegExpReplace(A2,"^([GSMP]\d+(\.\d+)?).*$","$1")
```

We wrapped the part we were interested in keeping in parentheses because the "$1" as part of the replacement pattern says to use whatever was found inside the first set of parentheses.  Here is that formula used in Excel
[image]

This works for all your examples but the last one, which is your else clause in your logic.  We can fix that by testing whether the pattern matched using RegExpMatch:

```
=IF(regexpMatch(A2,"^([GSMP]\d+(\.\d+)?).*$"),RegExpReplace(A2,"^([GSMP]\d+(\.\d+)?).*$","$1"),"Overhead")
```

This gives the results you are looking for and you have also gained a powerful text manipulation tool to solve future problems.
[image]

Comment: Note: I saved these wrapper functions as an Excel add-in (.XLAM and added it into my Excel implementation.  Now these formulas are automatically loaded every time I start up Excel and I don't have to fool around with Visual Basic every time I want to use them.

Comment: Great, it is the first time i heard this function. thanks, chris