# How to limit the email domains in an Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel with 150 rows with different Email Addresses for different companies. There is one row per company. Each cell contains multiple (up to 26) email addresses in the following format:

- peace@google.com;love@google.com;run@abc.com;life@facebook.com
- red@twitter.com;blue@twitter.com
- yellow@facebook.com;brown@facebook.com
- sky@instagram.com;tree@twitter.com

I want to limit the email domains that can be used in each row and have a column to indicate if an invalid email domain in being used. In the example above, the following domains should be accepted for each row:

- @google.com, @abc.com
- @twitter.com
- @facebook.com
- @instagram.com

This means that I should have a column with the following status for each row:

- Fail
- Pass
- Pass
- Fail

Is there a way I can do this with an Excel formula?

Thank you!

I have an idea:

1. Take the email domains
2. Remove duplicated ones as there are multiple addresses with the same domain
3. Create a database of accepted domains per company
4. Compare how many different domains are being used for each row and how many are accepted for the respective company.

The problem is that I am lost with the first two steps as I don't know how to extract the domains for multiple emails in a single cell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A4,B1:B4,LAMBDA(a,b,@SORT(IF(ISNA(XMATCH("@"&DROP(TEXTSPLIT(a,"@",";"),,1),TEXTSPLIT(b,", "))),"Fail","Pass"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated the formula code to specs:

```
=LET(
    emails, A3:A6,
    accept, B3:B6,
    a, MAP(
        emails,
        LAMBDA(e,
            TEXTJOIN(
                ",",
                ,
                SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTAFTER(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(e, , ";")), "@")))
            )
        )
    ),
    b, MAP(
        accept,
        LAMBDA(e, TEXTJOIN(",", , SORT(UNIQUE(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(e, , ","))))))
    ),
    MAP(a, b, LAMBDA(x, y, IF(x = y, "PASS", "FAIL")))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Cary! This formula only works if there is one acceptable domain per row. What if there can be multiple domains accepted for one company? For example, in the first row both "@google.com" and "@abc.com" should be accepted (in this case it is failed because there is also "@facebook.com")

Comment: Ok, I read something wrong. Let me rework it.

Comment: OK, Check it out now.

Comment: Don't use the "@" symbol at the start of your acceptable domain column, because Excel will think it is a formula instead of text. Just put "domain.com".

Comment: This formula also assumes that you separate your emails with the semicolon and your unique domains with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=MAP(A1:A4,B1:B4,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(a,";"),"@"),b))),"Pass","Fail")))
```

It splits the adresses in column A into an array. Only the text string after the `@` including a precediy `@` is checked to be present in the same row of column B. If all are found it returns `Pass` else `Fail`.

Comment: Excellent formula! But why does it work only with the AND function wrapped around the first IF argument. It should technically work without it.

Comment: The AND is wrapped around the splitted mail addresses from column A per row. It checks if all the values of the array are found within the string in column B for the same row. It only returns `TRUE` if all addresses meet the condition. This is what happens without AND: `=MAP(A1:A4,B1:B4,LAMBDA(a,b,CONCAT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(a,";"),"@"),b)))))`.

Comment: I see, by each cell, the AND function is validating an array for TRUEs and FALSES.  I had to go step by step in the formula to see it. Thanks so much, learning has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression match function, but first you must enable the regular expressions within excel.  Here is a link to a previous answer I gave that explains what you must do to [enable regular expressions in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606680/excel-findjobcodes-problems/68607105?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C6.5336#68607105).

Once you are finished with the above two-step process, you will now have 2 new Excel Functions RegExpMatch() & RegExpReplace() that you can use in cell formulas.  You will want to use RegExpMatch, which returns a true if the string matches a pattern and false if it does not match.

So, let's say your email addresses are in cell B2.  In A2 you would enter the formula:

```
=RegExpMatch(B2,"^([\w.-]+@(google|abc|facebook|twitter|instagram)\.com(;|$)){1,26}$")
```

If you have never seen a regular expression before, this one says 'starting at the beginning of the string [`^`] scan multiple (but at least one) occurrences of an alphanumeric, underscore, dot or dash [`[\w.-]+`]. Then look for an 'atsign' [`@`], then look for your 5 acceptable email mailers [`(google|abc|facebook|twitter|instagram)`], then a dot com [`\.com`]. Lastly look for either a semicolon or the end of the string [`(;|$)`], then repeat that pattern anywhere from 1 to 26 times [`{1,26}`]. If it fails anywhere, return a false, if it succeeds everywhere return true.

After you got it working on B2 you can fill it down for the other companies.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to save the workbook as a macro-enabled workbook (.XLSM) or else the VBA function wrappers won't be saved.